# can we use an aldready prepared SQLITE database for a phonegap application?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have doubt with respect to the database in the Phonegap domain.can we use a .sqlite (database) that's ready to use for a Phonegap domain.

I have tried it using the SQLITE plugin,but that creates a new SQLITE database with 1 table.

Prior to this i included a .sqlite file (database) in the assets/www folder.that is not being recognized.

Is it that i have to create a new database for which i already have one?